# loop html5 video using ended event broken

Tags: html, loops, video, html5-video

I am searching for the holy grail of a simple looping html5 video, I am currently using the following code which doesn't seem work

```
<video width="650" height="650" class="outer_shadow" autoplay="" ended="this.play()" loop>
    <source src="/videos?video_id=ag1kZXZ-anQtd2luZG93cg4LEghUaW1lRGF0YRgNDA">
</video>
```

Can anyone could hilight why this code doesn't work/suggest their best work arround?

Answer (score 1):

Surely you just need to set the `loop` attribute (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMHMt/) tested in Chrome):

```
<video id="myVideo" width="650" height="650" class="outer_shadow" autoplay loop>
    <source src="http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/nPripu9l-60830.mp4">
</video>​
```

If firefox still doesn't like the `loop` attribute, try the following fix:

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', function(){
    this.currentTime = 0;
}, false);
```

**Update:**

Perhaps not as simple as you had hoped but, as a work around for the problem, it might be worth trying one of the many HTML5 video libraries such as [video.js](http://videojs.com/). If the problem persists you could, as a worst case, force the library to use Flash where supported (ie. desktop) and fall-back to HTML5 where it's not (as explained [here](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/questions/147-force-use-of-flash-player)).

Comment: apparently if your video server does not have partial content requests enabled then the loop attribute is ignored by chrome, I should have added this to my initial question. The script you have above, am i correct in saying that i just ned to place it inside <script> tags and give the video element an id of 'myVideo', if so the problem still persists for me

Comment: Are you able to create a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem or link to your example?

Comment: this is an example fo the video file i have to work with (http://jsfiddle.net/AvqUy/)

Comment: Yeah looks like chrome's doing some odd stuff. If you let it play through and then right-click and select play from the context menu, it doesn't play either. This would suggest to me that there is no client-side work around for the problem. As you observe, it seems like the "ended" event is not fired by Chrome. My idea was to listen for the 'timeupdate' event (which is fired) and loop the video just before it gets to the end (http://jsfiddle.net/AvqUy/11/), but this doesn't work either. I take it you can't fix your server / find another one?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm stuck with it for now, I'll have to keep looking for a workarround

Comment: i just tried with the video.js and it seems to use the "ended" event so my video still doesn't loop

Comment: Even if you force it into Flash mode?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2knz6sv/) with working example of HTML5 video player that loops several videos. Just add your URLs to src array...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" width="500" height="400" controls autoplay></video>
<script>
var src = [
 "http://content.adfox.ru/131007/adfox/205544/865991_11.mp4",
 "http://all.rutube.ru/130627/gpmdigital/217059/805529_11.mp4"
];
var curSrc = 0;
$(function() {
 $('#video').attr("src", src[curSrc % src.length]);
 curSrc++;
 var video = $('#video').get(0);

 $('#video')
 .on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  video.currentTime=0.01;
  video.play();
 })
 .on('ended', function() {
  console.log('ended');
  video.src = src[curSrc % src.length];
  video.load();
  curSrc++;
 });
});
</script>
```